# Initializing a php download from a jQuery Noty Button

Tags: php, jquery, download

I'm trying to initiate a download with PHP when button in jquery noty is clicked. I'm getting blank page when the noty is supposed to appear and no errors in firebug console.

```
var noty_id = noty({
text: 'blah',
type: 'success',
buttons: [
    {addClass: 'btn btn-primary', text: 'Download', onClick: function($noty) {

        $noty.close();
        <?php

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            readfile($file);
            exit;
        }
        ?>  
    }}
]
});
```

Comment: What exactly is "noty"?

Comment: http://needim.github.com/noty/

Comment: You are mixing PHP code inside of your JS code.  This is OK for basic strings and variables, but you seem to try to execute PHP code when a button is clicked (on the client side).  You might want to read up on "AJAX" for interaction between the server and client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working without ajax. I changed line 64 from jquery.noty.js

From:

```
var $buttons = $('<div/>').addClass('noty_buttons');
```

To:

```
var $buttons = $("<form method='post'><input type='hidden' name='download' id='download'</form>").addClass('noty_buttons');
```

I then assigned value to the hidden field during the noty call:

```
var noty_id = noty({
    text: 'blah',
    type: 'success',
    buttons: [
        {addClass: 'btn btn-primary', text: 'Download', onClick: function($noty) {

            document.getElementById('download').value = file;
            $noty.close();  
        }}
   ]
 });
```

after that all is left is to initiate the download after the form is posted

```
<?php    
if(isset($_POST['download']))
{    
    $file = $_POST['download']);

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }   
}
?>
```